# How to add Google Ads in a Feed after every 'n' number of Post using next.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, tailwind-css

I want to create a feed where a Google Ad is shown after every 10 posts just like Instagram. I am using Firebase as my database and tailwind-CSS for the styling. How would I use Google Ads to implement this feature?

Here is my code for displaying a Feed

**Feed.js**

```
import {React, useState, useEffect} from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Post from "./Post";
import { onSnapshot, collection, query, orderBy } from "@firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../firebase";

function Feed() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(
    () =>
      onSnapshot(
        query(collection(db, "posts"), orderBy("timestamp", "desc")),
        (snapshot) => {
          setPosts(snapshot.docs);
        }
      ),
    [db]
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="pb-72">
        {posts.map((post) => (
          <Post key={post.id} id={post.id} post={post.data()} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Feed;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript `map` function has a second parameter - `index` - that tells you the index of the item in the array it is iterating. So you would want to make two key changes:

```js
return (
  <div>
    <Navbar />
    <div className="pb-72">
      {posts.map((post, idx) => {
         // If true, you're on the tenth post
         const isTenthPost = (idx + 1) % 10 === 0

         // Note the addition of the React fragment brackets - your map call
         // has to return a single React component, so we add this to handle
         // the case where we want to return both the post and the Google ad.
         return (
           <>
             <Post key={post.id} id={post.id} post={post.data()} />
             { isTenthPost && <GoogleAdComponent /> }
           </>
         )
      })}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

I'm not suggesting you copy and paste this exactly, but it should help you understand how to determine if you're on the nth post and how to conditionally display another component.